# Exponentiation of real numbers

Tags: algorithm, user-defined-functions, pascal, exponential, exponentiation

I've come across an interesting exercise and it says: **Implement a function x^y using standard functions of Turbo Pascal**

For `integer` variables I can use `for` loop but I cannot understand how to work with `real` variables in this case.

I've been thinking about how to do this using **Taylor series** (can't understand how to use it for exponentiation) and I also found out that `x^y = exp(y*log(x))` but there is only `ln` (natural logarithm) in standard functions...

**PS**
 I'm not asking you to write code: give me advise or link or something that will help to solve this problem, please.

Comment: If only log base is the issue then you can apply log formula and change bases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

log(x) in your formula is natural logarithm, so you can use

```
x^y = exp(y*ln(x))
```

without any doubts. Both **exp** and **ln** are standard Turbo Pascal functions

(general formula is  x^y = b^(y * base-b logarithm of x)

Comment: Thanks, I'll verify it. But could you explain how did you find out that `log(x)` int the question is `ln(x)`, please?

Comment: log(x) is abstract logarithm without base indication. Exp using implies natural logarithm.

Answer (score 1):

log x base y = ln(x) / ln(y) = (log x base 10)/(log y base 10)

Following link has more information regarding logarithms. Check out the "Changing the Base" section.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities

You can change your base to natural logarithm and compute accordingly.

```
For x = 3.2, y = 2.5,
Say 3.2^2.5 = m
ln(m) = 2.5*ln(3.2)
Hence m = exp( 2.5 * ln(3.2) )
```

Actually for the above, you do not even need to change bases

Comment: How can it be applied for `x:= 3.2` and `y:= 2.5`, for example?